# binary string with leading zeros issue

Tags: java, string-formatting, binaryformatter

I have a string which is converted in binary format but the binary conversion method removes it leading zero's and I am not sure how much leading zero's I should add in the start .It depends on the string my code is as follows

```
public static void encodeString(String str){
        byte[] bytes=str.getBytes();
        String binary = new BigInteger(bytes).toString(2);

    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ecaxtly? A big integer has no leading zeros, neither does a byte, short or int. 
Your question "I am not sure how much leading zero's I should add " can only be answered by yourself: as many as you want to have.

Comment: Show us a input/output example to see what you want.

Comment: I know there is no leading zeros in BigInteger like I want to achieve that lets suppose my input is "test" its binary should be  01110100011001010111001101110100 (with leading zero ) but my method gives me output "1110100011001010111001101110100" without leading zero like it is easy for me i can append zero at the start of string  it works fine, but if the input  is changed sometimes I need to append may be more then one zeros at the start i just want to have the exact idea about how to guess these leading zero

Comment: You can try something like this: `System.out.println(String.format("%64s", binary).replace(" ", "0"));` For this I am assuming that the String is not more than 64 characters long and replacing the further spaces with leading 0s.

Comment: I have tried this but it creates more than required zero's at the beginning for me this binary input will be used for encryption and I need to encrypt each bit with more than required zero it will be overhead or performance issues in my program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to preserve the 8-bits representation of each character of your input `String`.
to do so, I used this method:

```
    public static String byteFormat(String src) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {

        char chr = src.charAt(i);
        String format= String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(chr)).replace(' ', '0');
        sb.append(format);
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

and I tested it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(byteFormat("test"));
}
```

}

it outputs :
`01110100011001010111001101110100`

Comment: For the numbers it's showing weird results. For example if I pass `byteFormat("1")`, then it shows me `00110001`. Shouldn't that be just `00000001`?

Comment: I think the request is to convert the ascii code of  `"1"` to its byte format, not to fill in the empty leading bits

Comment: @mustabelMo understood my mistake. :) thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of leading zeroes would normally not matter, It's the same number anyways.

You can always left pad to the amount of zeroes you want manually

Comment: If I append more then required zero's at the start it looks like that output has some blanked spaces which I dont want