# Convert Binary to Hex and Hex to Binary

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
    public static String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binaryStr) 
    {
        return new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2).toString(16);
    }
    public static String convertHexadecimalToBinary(String hexStr)
    {
        return new BigInteger(hexStr, 16).toString(2);
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String binaryStr = "01011111";
        String myhexStr = convertBinaryToHexadecimal(binaryStr);
        System.out.println(myhexStr);
        String myBinStr = convertHexadecimalToBinary(myhexStr);
        System.out.println(myBinStr);
    }
}
```

Hi everyone. I'm trying to convert Binary to Hexadecimal and Vice  Versa. I got a problem when I convert from Hexadecimal to Binary.
My string Binary is "01011111", when I convert to Hexa the output is 5f which is correct but when I convert back to Binary, the output is 1011111 which is missing 0 at the front. How can I fix it?

Comment: No. I didn't ask that question

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444872/binary-string-with-leading-zeros-issue

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
   public static String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binaryStr) 
   {
      return new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2).toString(16);
   }
   public static String convertHexadecimalToBinary(String hexStr)
   {
      return new BigInteger(hexStr, 16).toString(2);
      
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      String binaryStr = "01011111";
      String myhexStr = convertBinaryToHexadecimal(binaryStr);
      System.out.println(myhexStr);
      String myBinStr = convertHexadecimalToBinary(myhexStr);
      
      if(myBinStr.length()<8){
         myBinStr = "0" + myBinStr;
         System.out.println(myBinStr);
      } 
      
      else{
         System.out.println(myBinStr);
      }
   }
}
```